# For some users, both POST and GET simultaneously submitted (double request) from Ajax POST JS

Tags: jquery, ajax, tomcat, post, http-post

In very rare cases, we get users whose browsers submit **double POST and GET pairs** for an expected **POST** request coming from Ajax JS.

That is, if we have

```
$.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        url : '/myapp/insertEvent',   
        data : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({'test' : 'test')) 
    });
```

the Apache log shows a double POST + GET submission. But most users never generate this condition, they submit just 1 POST request. In extremely rare cases, for some users (<0.001%), we see these pairs, which cause problems for us:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [10/Nov/2020:09:44:20 -0500] "POST /myapp/insertEvent HTTP/1.1" 200 4 followed by

1.2.3.4 - - [10/Nov/2020:09:44:20 -0500] "GET /myapp/insertEvent HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

I wasn't sure where to place this question, since it could affect many different areas, but what could be causing this rare glitch for some users?

In one case, it was a Mac user with this browser:

- **Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0**

Is there something wrong with this browser? Or is something else at fault? Could it be a Tomcat issue (we're using Tomcat 8.5, Spring 5)?

---

CODE DETAIL

Button click goes into a function

```
$('#buttonAddEventItemTop).click(function() {
    addEventItem();
});
```

The function makes an Ajax request returning a `promise` with `.then() / .fail()` . It checks the return from the promise sequence to determine if an error box should be displayed or not.

```
return $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        url : '/app/insertEvent',   
        data : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({'test' : 'test'}))        
    })
    .then(function() {
        //...
    })
    .then(function() {
        //...
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //...
    });
```

jQuery Version: **jquery-2.2.4** Code works 99% of the time, it's a very rare issue.

Comment: When do you make the AJAX request? Is it when a `form` element is submit?

Comment: It's when a button is clicked. There is no form submit; just regular buttons with onclick functions that call Ajax requests.

Comment: We need to see more of your HTML and JS code in order to debug this. The code that you've shown will not cause the behaviour you describ

Comment: I added some more code and details. It's an `.ajax().then().then().fail()` promise-based sequence. jQuery 2.2.4.

Comment: What other events are bound to the click of `#buttonAddEventItemTop`, or any of its parent elements, and what other logic is performed in `addEventItem()`?